# Native Xml handling or (external) lib

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I've multiple projects with each different configurations, all these configurations must be specified in a single XML file. That isn't the app.config but is specified on a generic location.

My current project structure:

- core project (with some XML)
- subproject (need to access the core XML configuration in a generic way + own configuration from the same XML file)

Which .NET XML technology is the best suitable for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would also suggest renaming the post title to something like "Native Xml handling or external lib", the C# isn't necessary in the title as the tag is already there and your current title doesn't aptly reflect the post content at the moment

Comment: I would use `Linq To Xml` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution for the problem:

With LINQ to XML I'm taken the XML element that matches an object. This XML element is below one level deeper than the root. With this way I am first 'filtering' the root tags and than converts this to string to objects with deserialization.

For example

```
<root>
    <project1>
       <somevalue>myvalue</somevalue>
    </project1>
    <project2/>
</root>
```

If I wanted everything from project1 I'm getting the string with descendants with LINQ to XML and then deserialize the string to the corresponding object(s).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read anything in your post to suggest, that the built-in Xml functionality of the .Net framework wouldn't be up to the task.

I work with Xml on an almost daily basis and I've, as of yet, never needed any external libraries. It all depends on your project requirements of course, but you've got two projects that will use the same functionality so you could (and should) easily make an abstraction and isolation of the Xml handling for both projects, either referencing your own core\xml classes in the subproject or (my preference) in a separate dll project. A dll could serve you well in the future.

An added bonus to writing your own Xml functionality is, that you gather more intimate knowledge of the inner workings of the .Net Xml namespace, knowledge that in no way is ever wasted, whereas you would distance yourself from it by using external libraries (that are often no more than wrappers and façades for the .Net classes)

Hope this is somewhat helpful and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The app.config file is probably the best suited for this. You can create your own configuration sections and the single configuration file for the project is accessible to all referenced assemblies, so each assembly can have its own section.
You can also have user specific configuration in user.config (see [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)).

If you cannot use the app.config because it needs to be in a specific location you can always load an app.config file from a different location with `ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`

Other alternatives:

- Use the `XmlSerializer` to deserialize an XML into a POCO with your configuration.
- The masochistic option: Use plain `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` to manually parse your configuration file on the fly.